# Хеширование md5-файла

Tags: php, md5

Имеется PHP-скрипт, который хеширует файлы из папки "update" в md5:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'update/';
    $file = 'update.upd';
    $separator = '[cell]';
    file_put_contents($file,''); 
    function rdir ($path2dir) {
        $d = dir ($path2dir);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if ($entry!='.' && $entry!='..' && $entry!='' ) {
                $all_path = $path2dir.$entry;
                $new_path = go ($all_path, is_file($all_path));
                if (!is_file($all_path)) {
                    if (!rdir ($new_path)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function go ($path2file, $is_file = true) {
        if ($is_file) {
            $as = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/'.$path2file.$separator.md5_file($path2file).$separator.substr($path2file,strrpos($path2file,'\\')+6).'\n';         
            $fh = fopen($file, 'a+');
            fwrite($fh, $as);
        } else {
            $path2file = $path2file.'/';         
        }
        return $path2file;
    }
    if (rdir ($folder)){echo('OK');}
?>
```

При открытии этого файла в браузере, должно быть выведено сообщение "ОК", а в директории, где находится скрипт, появится файл "`update.upd`", который будет содержать в себе хэш-суммы.
При открытии файла в браузере выводится подобное:

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in
>   T:\home\ixcraft.local\launcher\md5.php on line 24 Warning: fwrite()
>   expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   T:\home\ixcraft.local\launcher\md5.php on line 25

Проблема в функциях *fopen()* и *fwrite()*, - это и так всем понятно.
***Вопрос***: как решить данную проблему, в чём ошибка?

Comment: ну так достаточно лишь перевести warning-cообщение и сразу все станет понятно. Даже написано в какой строке ошибки. Как же Вам не стыдно такие вопросы задавать.

Comment: Переводил, но исправить так и не смог, к сожалению. Поэтому решил задать вопрос.

Comment: У Вас в строке 24 в переменной $file пусто. Вам нужно ей присвоить хоть что-то :) А ошибка в строке 25 вытекает из строки 24.

Comment: Конечно он пуст, ведь скрипт должен записать в него хэш-суммы, которые, по каким-то причинам, не записываются. И эти причины я не могу найти..

Comment: Вы серьезно? 
Перечитайте мое предыдущее сообщение. Там не написано, что файл пуст. Там написано, что переменная $file пустая. То есть ей ничего не присвоено. То есть и открывать функции fopen тоже нечего. Улавливаете?

Comment: Упс, и в правду: не уловил мысль в предыдущем комментарии, но ведь переменной дано значение. Смотрите код, там есть эта переменная.
 $file = 'update.upd'; - или я опять не догоняю? !genius!

Comment: Да всё верно, ей присвоено значение. Но эта переменная не глобальная. А у функций есть область видимости и переменная $file находится за этой областью. Так что переменная $file в функции go() это не та же самая переменная $file, которую вы объявили в начале.

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему посредством изменения переменной $file в переменную $is_file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было прописать вместо:
*`fopen($file, 'a+');`*
**это:**
*`fopen($is_file, 'a+');`*